# Can I pass diferent type parameter to the same function?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

### I have a function:

```
/*This function spawns a GameObject randomly at another GameObject's position and it takes 3 arguments:
Argument 1. type GameObject: the game object that will be spawned.
         2. type Transform[]: the GameObject will be spawned at this Transform position.
         3. type float: the distance that the camera must travel before the GameObject will be spawned. */
void SpawnPylon(GameObject whatSpawn, Transform[] whereSpawn, float spawnDistance)
{
    bool hasSpawnedPylon = false;

    if (currPosition != (int)transform.position.z)
    {
        if ((int)transform.position.z % spawnDistance == 0)
        {
            if (!hasSpawnedPylon)
            {
                //this makes the GameObject spawn randomly
                spawnIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);
                //This is instantiationg the GameObject
                Instantiate (whatSpawn, whereSpawn [spawnIndex].position, whereSpawn [spawnIndex].rotation);
                //this makes shore that the GameObject is not spawned multiple times at aproximetley the same position.
                currPosition = (int)transform.position.z;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hasSpawnedPylon = false;
    }
}
```

As you can see the function takes 3 arguments of type : `GameObject`, `Transform[]` and `float`.

How can I make it that I can give a type `Transform` instead of `Transform[]`.

More specifically, how can I make a function to accept parameters of more different types, without actually needing te pass every single parameter:

So, for example I can call the function using different types such as this:

```
`SpawnPylon(GameObject ,Transform[] ,float`)
```

And then do this:

```
SpawnPylon(GameObject ,Transform ,float)
```

Or do this:

```
SpawnPylon(GameObject, string, float)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can define method overloads with different signatures that call the original method.

Comment: Can you show me a way of doing that, just a little example or something.

Comment: @DinuAdrian you can Google "method overload c#", you'll find dozens of web pages and tutorials. This is a very old feature, and EVERY book about C# teaches about that.

Comment: @DinuAdrian: I've added an answer

Comment: Your question is too broad. It is not clear what you expect to happen with each overload you want to define. If you'd just asked about the first two, it's _possible_ you could have changed the single method declaration to look like `void SpawnPylon (GameObject whatSpawn, float spawnDistance, params Transform[] whereSpawn)`. Then the compiler would automatically treat a call like `SpawnPylon(gameObject, float, transform)` as if you'd called it like `SpawnPylon(gameObject, float, new [] { transform })`.

Comment: You could even call it like `SpawnPylon(gameObject, float, transform1, transform2)` in that case, and the compiler would treat it like you'd passed a two-element array. But none of that would address a `string` type parameter, nor is it clear from your question what your method would do with a `string` parameter. In any case, method overloading is a well-known and well-documented technique. You should do some research before pursuing this question further.

Answer (score 4):

You can overload your method to have a different signature, and then call the original. For example:

```
void SpawnPylon(GameObject whatSpawn, Transform whereSpawn, float spawnDistance) {
  SpawnPylon(whatSpawn, new Transform[] {whereSpawn}, spawnDistance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the type in a signature of a method you will have to overload your method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx

Have you looked into Using an Indeterminate Number of Parameters?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228391(v=vs.90).aspx

To handle the cases you have ask for your, the interface of your class could look like this:

```
void SpawnPylon(GameObject whatSpawn, float spawnDistance, params Transform[] whereSpawn);
void SpawnPylon(GameObject whatSpawn, float spawnDistance, string whereSpawn);
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
SpanPylon(game, distance, where1);
```

or

```
SpanPylon(game, distance, where1, where2);
```

or

```
SpanPylon(game, distance, whereString);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want pass parameter type what you want.. Use object.

```
void SpawnPylon (GameObject whatSpawn,object whereSpawn,float spawnDistance)
{

    if(whereSpawn is Transform[])
    {
//put your Transform[] specific codes here
    }

if(whereSpawn is Transform)
    {
//put your Transform specific codes here
    }

if(whereSpawn is String)
    {
//put your String specific codes here
    }

}
```